# Right-justifying vertical subfigures in a two-column document

Tags: subfloats, two-column, adjustbox

I am trying to include a pair of subfigures in my two-column document, stacked one on top of the other.  I want them to be right-justified; to achieve this with individual figures I have been using the `adjustbox` package.  When I try to use this package with the subfigures however, it stops laying them out one on top of the other - despite the new line command.  A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twocolumn]{article}
%Used for figures
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% Document margins
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1,top=32mm,columnsep=20pt]{geometry} 
%Deals with paragraph formatting
\usepackage{parskip}
%Allows sub-floats
\usepackage{subcaption}
%Text
\usepackage{lipsum}

%-------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

%Stop stretching of text on last page
\raggedbottom

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{right}
        \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.6\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph1}
                \caption{Graph1.}
                \label{fig:graph1}
        \end{subfigure}
\\
     \begin{subfigure}[H]{0.6\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph2}
                \caption{Graph2.}
                \label{fig:graph2}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Graphs}\label{fig:graphs}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `\columnwidth` could be better than `\textwidth`!

Comment: I didnt actually know there was a `\columnwidth` variable, thanks! Although it doesn't fix my problem, as I want the floats to be wider than a column and they are still justified left - making them overlap with the other column.

Comment: Don't use the `[H]` placement specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the two subfigures stacked vertically and sticking out to the left by encasing them in *separate* `adjustbox` environments. Incidentally, observe that there's no point in specifying the `[H]` positioning specifier for the two `subfigure` environments. And, as @Sigur has already noted in a comment, do use `\columnwidth` rather than `\textwidth` for the widths of the `subfigure`s and `\linewidth` for the width of the graphs.

To reproduce just the figure-related code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{right}
   \begin{subfigure}{1.2\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{graph1}
      \caption{Graph1.}
      \label{fig:graph1}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{adjustbox}

\begin{adjustbox}{right}
   \begin{subfigure}{1.2\columnwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{graph2}
      \caption{Graph2.}
      \label{fig:graph2}
   \end{subfigure}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{Graphs}\label{fig:graphs}
\end{figure}
```

The resulting figure looks like this (note that I had to load the `graphicx` package since you didn't post the graphs referenced in the code):

[image]